# Spotify docker-gc: prevent auto stop after first run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I tried to use [docker-gc](https://github.com/spotify/docker-gc) for automatically collecting unused docker images and containers. I tried this config in `docker-compose` for running:

```
gc:
  container_name: docker-gc
  build: ./docker/docker-gc
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - /etc:/etc
```

When I first run, all unused docker images and containers are removed automatically. But after that, this container exit. I want this container runs and check periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach:

Use `cron` to run `docker-compose` periodically.

About exiting container:

Containers run a `script/service` until its `finished/killed`.
For example `library/nginx` runs `nginx` service. The container will be in `running` state until the `nginx` service `stopped/killed`. Then it will show up as exited with appropriate exit code.

`entrypoint/cmd` directive will specify what `script/service` container will execute when run with no user override.